# How to Accept [ENTER] key as an invalid input and send out error message

Tags: c++, validation, enter

This is a program that grade user inputs for the questions of Driver's License Exam. 
I'm having trouble of validating the user input.

I'd like to accept the [ENTER] key as an invalid input and proceed to my validation rather than just go to an empty line and cannot process to the next question. Purpose is to send out error message and that no input is given and [ENTER] key is not valid input and only accept one more chance to enter valid input which are a/A, b/B, c/C, or d/D. So that is why I'm using if statement here instead of loop.

I tried if (testTakerAnswers[ans] == (or =) '\n') {} but still doesn't solve the problem of newline.

I include curses.h in here hope to use getch() statement from the other post but somehow I can't manage to work in my code with an array instead of regular input.

I'm looking for other methods as well rather than getch()

So should I adjust my bool function, or directly validate input in main() function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <curses.h>

using namespace std;

const unsigned SIZE = 20;       // Number of qns in the test
char testTakerAnswers[SIZE];    //Array to hold test taker's answers
bool validateInput(char);

class TestGrader
{
private:
    char answers[SIZE];        // Holds the correct answers // Answer is array
    int getNumWrong (char[]);
    void missedQuestions (char[]);

public:
    void setKey(string);   // Initialize object with standard keys
    void grade(char[]);     // Grades the answers from tester

};
void TestGrader::setKey(string key){
    if (key.length()!=SIZE){
        cout << "Error in key data.\n";
        return;
    }
    for (unsigned pos = 0; pos < SIZE ; pos ++)
        answers [pos] = key [pos];
}

void TestGrader::grade(char test[])
{
    int numWrong = getNumWrong(test);
    if (numWrong <= 5)
        cout << "Congratulations. You passed the exam.\n";
    else
        cout << "You did not pass the exam. \n";
    cout << "You got " << (SIZE-numWrong) << " questions correct. \n";
    if (numWrong > 0){
        cout << "You missed the following " << numWrong << " questions: \n";
        missedQuestions(test);

    }
}

int TestGrader::getNumWrong(char test[])
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        if (answers[i] != toupper(testTakerAnswers[i])){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

void TestGrader::missedQuestions(char test[])
{
    //  cout << testTakerAnswers[i];        This is to print taker's answers
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        if (answers[i] != toupper(testTakerAnswers[i])){
            cout << "\n" << i + 1 << ". Correct answers: " << answers[i];
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

bool validateInput(char ans){           // Only A, B, C, D valid input
    if (toupper(ans)!='A' && toupper(ans)!= 'B' && toupper(ans)!='C'  && toupper(ans)!= 'D'){
        cout << "\n********************WARNING*******************\n";
        cout << "Invalid input! Enter only a/A, b/B, c/C, or d/D\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (testTakerAnswers[ans] == '\n'){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    const int NUM_QUESTIONS = 20;

    string name;                                 //Test taker's name
    char doAnother;                 //Control variable for main processing loop
    TestGrader DMVexam;                       //Create a TestGrader object

    DMVexam.setKey("BDAACABACDBCDADCCBDA");

    do {
        cout << "Applicant Name: ";
        getline(cin,name);
        cout << "Enter answer for " << name << ".\n";
        cout << "Use only letters a/A, b/B, c/C, and d/D. \n\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_QUESTIONS; i++){
            // Input and validate it
            do{
                cout << "Q" << i+1 << ": ";
                cin >> testTakerAnswers[i];

                if (!validateInput(testTakerAnswers[i])){

                    cout << "You get one more chance to correct.\nOtherwise, it count as wrong answer.";
                    cout << "\n*********************************************";
                    cout << "\nRe-enter: ";
                    cin >> testTakerAnswers[i];
                    cout << '\n';
                    break;
                }
            }while(!validateInput(testTakerAnswers[i]));
        }

        //Call class function to grade the exam
        cout << "Results for " << name << '\n';
        DMVexam.grade(testTakerAnswers);

        cout << "\nGrade another exam (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> doAnother;
        while (doAnother != 'Y' && doAnother != 'N' && doAnother != 'y' && doAnother != 'n'){
            cout << doAnother << " is not a valid option. Try Again y/Y or n/N" << endl;
            cin >> doAnother;}
        cout << endl;
        cin.ignore();

    }while(doAnother != 'N' && doAnother != 'n');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is `cin >> testTakerAnswers[i];` cin is whitespace delimited, that means that any whitespace (including '\n') will be discarded. So testTakerAnswers[i] can never be '\n'.

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but possibly try

```
getline(cin,input_string);
```

then

```
input_string == "A" | input_string == "B" | ...
```

So if only the enter key is pressed, `input_string` will become `""`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But since the input is char element in an array, does it still apply for this situation? Or I need to create another string variable for this?

Comment: For what I suggested, you will need to make a new string variable